# Wordpress cron schedule for every x hours

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have the following code to execute cron job in **every 3 hours** to display time in the head.But it **didn't work**.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpce_prefix_activation' );
function wpce_prefix_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( current_time ( 'timestamp' ), 10800, 'prefix_three_hourly_event_hook' );
}

add_action( 'prefix_three_hourly_event_hook', 'wpce_prefix_do_this_three_hourly' );
function wpce_prefix_do_this_three_hourly() {
    // do something every hour
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_link_in_head');

} // end function

function add_link_in_head(){
  echo time();

}//end of function

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpce_prefix_deactivation' );
function wpce_prefix_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'prefix_three_hourly_event_hook' );
}



    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'filter_cron_schedules' );
// add custom time to cron


 function filter_cron_schedules( $schedules ) {
        $schedules['fively'] = array(
            'interval' => 300,
            'display' => __('Once in Five minutes')
        ); 



$schedules['in_per_minute'] = array(
    'interval' => 60,
    'display' => __('In every minute')
);  

$schedules['in_per_ten_minute'] = array(
    'interval' => 600,
    'display' => __('Once in Ten minutes')
); 

$schedules['1_hours'] = array(
    'interval' => 3600,
    'display' => __('Hour')
);


$schedules['three_hourly'] = array(
    'interval' => 10800,
    'display' => __('Once in three hours')
);  
return $schedules;
}
```

I want to run the cron job in wordpress **every 3 hours,5 hours,6 and 7 hours**.

If anyone can help it would really appreciate.
Thank you

Comment: What exactly did you write in `crontab`?

Comment: I have create the custom link indexing plugin and after users submitted their links to db then run cron jobs to another web site after 3,5,6,7 hours for link indexing. in the above i just added time to display in the head for test purpose.